# 'require' is undefined when using reactjs.net along with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, reactjs.net

I am using Reactjs.NET within an MVC 5 project,
We have been able to combine Webpack with reactjs.net, but currently we are running into issues using external modules, for example (material-ui) within our react components directory. Since reactJs.NET doesn't support import we are trying to include those in the JSX components using the require statement, however we are getting a Script threw an exception: 'require' is undefined

any idea how we can include some of the modules that we have in our webpack bundle inside our jsx component?

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

[this issue](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/140) sounds like exactly what you're experiencing.

assuming you've gone through [this page](https://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html) then maybe the problem is related to having `npm install`ed webpack 2 which uses a different config.  check out [webpack's migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) for info on that.